# CMake find_package failure while looking for Qt5 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - cmake version mismatch

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake

I stumbled upon this problem while trying to find Qt5  with CMake.
Qt5 is installed on my Ubuntu through Ubuntu apt program, but there is an error occurring that looks like this:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:3 (message):
[cmake]   Qt5 requires at least CMake version 3.1.0
```

While my cmake version is 3.16.3 from Ubuntu repositories:

```
cmake version 3.16.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

And when i looked into Qt5Config.cmake file, the error happens on first line:

```
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 3.1.0)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Qt5 requires at least CMake version 3.1.0")
endif()
```

And i have no idea how to resolve it, other than changing `VERSION_LESS` to `VERSION_GREATER` in all `.cmake` files for Qt installation resolves the problem. (Which obviously, does not make any sense).

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you please share the CMakeLists.txt that you are trying to build? Probably in the top of that file the first line includes `cmake_minimum_required()`. That might be your problem

Comment: First line in my CMakeLists. txt does contain it: ```cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)```I cannot use ```cmake_minimum_required``` in my top CMakeLists.txt?